# predicting runtime of $\mathcal{O}(n \log(n))$ algorithm, one "input size to runtime" pair is given

Tags: algorithms, computer-science, asymptotics, logarithms

I'm given the runtimes for input size $n=100$ of some polynomial-time (big-Oh) algorithms and an $\mathcal{O}(n \log(n))$ one. I want to calculate the runtimes for:
$200$, $1000$ and $10000$.

For the polynomials it is trivial.
The results I should get for the $n \log n$ case are:
$0.06$, $1$ and $20$ seconds respectively, where $0.03s$ was given for $n=100$.

I have tried: (examples should have $0.06$ as solution)

(1) $\frac{f(2x)}{f(x)}$ similarly to how I've got the right solution to the polynomials, $\frac{2x \log(2x)}{x \log x} = \ldots= 2 \log((2x)^{1/\log x})$, not getting anywhere, and substituting $n=100$ gives $2.3010$ for any $\log$ base.

(2) calculating the "unit time of execution" $x$, from $100 x \log(100x)=0.03$
after approximating the inverse of $y=n \log n$ for $y=0.03$,
$n=1.03$ for natural $\log$, substitution gives: $1.48$.
$n=1.02058$ for binary $\log$, substitution gives: $2.10$

(3) calculating "unit time of execution" from the polynomial cases, which yield different for each, and result in negative runtimes predictions for the nlogn algorithm

(?) I also thought of searching for a function that is $\mathcal{O}(n \log n)$ and fits onto the points given by the solution, but thats over my head.

How to get to the solution ?
Did any of my attempts made sense ?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.
It probably just trying to emphasize the orders of growth, because it is a first assignment about computational complexity and big-Oh. But not knowing how the answer for that one case came along keeps bugging me, and I can't step over it for days now. Because it is a free online course, I can't just ask the TA.
Do you think that one column of the solution is simply wrong ? (section assignment 5, last problem from http://see.stanford.edu/see/materials/icspacs106b/assignments.aspx)

Comment: (I think this was supposed to be a comment to my answer, rather than a separate answer). Based on this new information, I'm quite certain that the solution set is simply wrong. I can see no justification for the numbers they give, much less any reason why a student would be expected to arrive at _those_ numbers in particular. Next time please add such links to the source of the problem to the question itself; that makes it much easier to figure out which kind of answer would be useful.

Comment: @nlognfan: your accounts have been merged. Please register your account to avoid creating duplicate accounts in the future.

Answer (score 3):

**Assuming this is a homework exercise**, I think you're making it much more complex than it is.

You're being asked (implicitly) to imagine that an input size of $100$ is enough that all run-time contributions of terms that grow *slower* than $n\log n$ -- such as time for the program to start up, the $O(n)$ time it takes to read the input, and so forth -- are insignificant compared to the $n\log n$ term. (This is not an unproblematic assumption -- see below -- but that may not be what the question asks you to philosophize about).

In other words, *suppose* you can ignore everything else. Then the running time is $f(n) = Cn\log n$ for some constant $C$. Given that $f(100)=0.03$, you can find $C$ simply by plugging in $100$ to get
$$C\cdot 100\log(100) = 0.03 \quad\text{ and therefore }\quad C = \frac{0.03}{200}=0.00015$$
Now you just use that $C$ to find $f(10000)=0.00015\times 10000\times 4=6$.
But that is not the result you're expecting to get -- why would you expect $f(10000)$ to be $20$?

It's not a result of using a base-10 logarithm, because any other logarithm would just show up as a multiplicative factor in $C$ that is canceled out when we plug in concrete numbers later.

You certainly *shouldn't* expect $f(100)=0.03$ and $f(200)=0.06$, because that amounts only to a *linear* scaling of the runtime with no logarithmic factor at all. (It's possible to get this behavior with a constant term, of course, but then your problem is underspecified).

**So perhaps it's not homework?** Are the known good values ones you have measured in practice? In that case it is very likely that what you see is just due to measuring uncertainty -- $0.03$ seconds is a very short time to time a program, and you really have no business trying to extrapolate that by a factor of 100. How precise are your measurements even for such short intervals?

For example, a problem of size 100 will likely stay within the L1 cache whereas for a size of 10000 you begin to pay a price in cache misses that simply doesn't show up at all in the $n=100$ measurement.

Remember that big-O notation is about how the resource usage grows when $n$ is *very large*, and a nice big-O analysis can hide *any amount* of shenanigans and erratic behavior for *small* $n$, as long as there is *some* size above which the complexity behaves as the big-O notation claims. There's no guarantee about how large this threshold may be; even 10000 may be too small a problem size to see the big-O complexity in action.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem (as reported here) is underspecified.

Recall the definition: $$f \in O(g) \textrm{ exactly when } \exists x_0, c > 0 \colon \forall x > x_0 \colon |f(x)| \leq cg(x)$$

Consider now some function $f$ and a family $h_k$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$, defined such that $h_k(x) = f(x)$ on the finite list of input-output pairs you are given, and $h_k(x) = f(x)/k$ for all other $x$.

If $f \in O(n \log n)$ then $h_k \in O(n \log n)$ for all $k > 0$.

Are you being asked to evaluate $h_1$ or $h_2$ or something else? If all you have is a finite list of input-output pairs and the fact that $g \in O(n \log n)$ where $g$ is the function you must evaluate, you don't have enough information since $g$ could be $h_k$ for any $k > 0$.

Requiring $g$ to be increasing won't save the question: instead, set $h_k(x) = f(x)$ on all $x$ up to and including the largest given input $x_m$, and $h_k(x) = f(x_m) + \frac{k}{k+1} (f(x_m) - f(x))$ whenever $x > x_m$. Note that $h_k$ is continuous for all $k$ if $f$ is so adding that requirement won't fix the question either.

The fundamental problem is that $O(\cdot)$ describes the behavior of functions asymptotically, and the description is too loose to compute specific values. If you are given that $g(x) \leq ax + b$ for some $a$ and $b$ and for all $x$, how would you find $g(200)$? You have no lower bound, and you only know that some upper bound exists but you don't know what $a$ and $b$ are. I guess your inputs constrain them but not enough (e.g. choose $b$ bigger than your largest output, then $a$ can be anything).

Side note, to motivate the above question: if $f$ is either monotonic or continuous and $g$ is either monotonic or continuous, and uh I think $g$ has to be eventually bounded below by a positive constant and their domains have to have a lower bound (e.g. 0), then $f \in O(g)$ is true exactly if there exists $a, b$ such that for all $x$ we have $f(x) \leq ag(x) + b$. (In one direction, let $a = c$ and let $b$ be the largest value $f$ takes before $x_0$. In the other, let $x_0$ be such that $g(x) > d > 0$ when $x > x_0$ and do algebra.)